# MongoDB aggregate/group/sum query translated to pymongo query

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a set of entries in the `goals` collection that looks like this:

```
{"user": "adam", "position": "attacker", "goals": 8}
{"user": "bart", "position": "midfielder", "goals": 3}
{"user": "cedric", "position": "goalkeeper", "goals": 1}
```

I want to calculate a sum of all goals. In MongoDB shell I do it like this:

```
> db.goals.aggregate([{$group: {_id: null, total: {$sum: "$goals"}}}])
{ "_id" : null, "total" : 12 }
```

Now I want to do the same in Python using pymongo. I tried using both `db.goals.aggregate()` and `db.goals.group()`, but no success so far.

Non working queries:

```
> query = db.goals.aggregate([{"$group": {"_id": None, "total": {"$sum": "$goals"}}}])
{u'ok': 1.0, u'result': []}

> db.goals.group(key=None, condition={}, initial={"sum": "goals"}, reduce="")
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input at $group reduce setup
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just use a **pipe** with **aggregate**.

```
pipe = [{'$group': {'_id': None, 'total': {'$sum': '$goals'}}}]
db.goals.aggregate(pipeline=pipe)

Out[8]: {u'ok': 1.0, u'result': [{u'_id': None, u'total': 12.0}]}
```