# Python - Aggregation of MongoDB with "match" condition

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to get a count of a value in my collection. Here's a sample:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("583e86987f22def116c35055"),
    "createdby" : "DEO007",
    "valid" : 1
}
```

In each document, some "valid" are 0 and some are 1. 
In my case, I only want the total count of documents grouped by "createdby" which has "valid" : 1.

I tried this in MongoDB and it worked without any error :

```
db.tme_data.aggregate([{ $match: { valid: 1 } },{"$group": {"_id":"$createdby" , "count":{"$sum":1}}}])
```

But I'm not able to implement the same in my python code. 
This is what I tried :

```
collection.aggregate([{"$match":{"$valid":"1"}}, {"$group": {"_id":"$createdby" , "count":{"$sum":1}}}])
```

It gave me a blank collection.

**PS:**

1) I'm using pymongo

2) This is working properly in my python code :

```
collection.aggregate([{"$group": {"_id":"$createdby" , "count":{"$sum":1}}}])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB aggregate/group/sum query translated to pymongo query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26465846/mongodb-aggregate-group-sum-query-translated-to-pymongo-query)

Comment: @user3632894 I even tried using pipe as explained in the solution to the question mentioned by you. But either the explanation is too concise or I am making some mistake. Either way, a more detailed solution would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you have `{"$valid":"1"}` in your python code. Its a field to be matched.

It should be `{"valid":"1"}`

Comment: I knew it was some small error. Thanks for pointing out. I made this mistake while copying this thing from my php code.

Comment: Can you explain why do I need to use $ with createdby in `db.tme_data.aggregate([{ $match: { valid: 1 } },{"$group": {"_id":"$createdby" , "count":{"$sum":1}}}]`?

Comment: $ is basically a literal. It provides access to a field. For better understanding refer: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/literal/#exp._S_literal