# pymongo aggregate query for nested document

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb

I have a nested document in mongodb for all the hot fixes applied on one particular computer.
The problem I am facing is with aggregate query to extract all the IDs and their corresponding hot fix type.

The query I am using is :-

db.collection.find({'Update_Type.**KB2868626**.InstalledOn' : { $gte : ISODate("2013-11-14T00:00:00Z")}},{_id: 1, 'Update_Type.**KB2868626**.Hotfix.$' : 1});

The Query has been run on mongo shell and it gives me the output. However, query contains static KB2868626 Id.

I have a structure like this:-

> {
>       "_id" : "TEST_2019-02-19 11:59:23.022557",
>       "DateandTime" : ISODate("2019-02-19T11:59:23.022Z"),
>       "Hostname" : "TEST",
>       "Update_Type" : {
>           "KB2868626" : [
>               {
>                   "Hotfix" : "Security Update",
>                   "InstalledOn" : ISODate("2013-11-14T00:00:00Z")
>               }
>           ],
>           "KB2883200" : [
>               {
>                   "Hotfix" : "Update",
>                   "InstalledOn" : ISODate("2013-11-14T00:00:00Z")
>               }
>           ],
>           "KB2887595" : [
>               {
>                   "Hotfix" : "Update",
>                   "InstalledOn" : ISODate("2013-11-14T00:00:00Z")
>               }
>           ],
>           "KB2894179" : [
>               {
>                   "Hotfix" : "Update",
>                   "InstalledOn" : ISODate("2013-11-14T00:00:00Z")
>               }
>           ],
>           "KB2900986" : [
>               {
>                   "Hotfix" : "Security Update",
>                   "InstalledOn" : ISODate("2013-11-14T00:00:00Z")
>               }
>           ],
>           "KB2919355" : [
>               {
>                   "Hotfix" : "Update",
>                   "InstalledOn" : ISODate("2018-02-24T00:00:00Z")
>               }
>           ],
>           "KB2919442" : [
>               {
>                   "Hotfix" : "Update",
>                   "InstalledOn" : ISODate("2018-02-24T00:00:00Z")
>               }
>           ],
>           "KB2959977" : [
>               {
>                   "Hotfix" : "Update",
>                   "InstalledOn" : ISODate("2018-02-24T00:00:00Z")
>               }
>           ],
>           "KB2992611" : [
>               {
>                   "Hotfix" : "Security Update",
>                   "InstalledOn" : ISODate("2018-02-24T00:00:00Z")
>               }
>           ],
>           "KB2999226" : [
>               {
>                   "Hotfix" : "Update",
>                   "InstalledOn" : ISODate("2018-08-02T00:00:00Z")
>               }
>           ],
>           "KB3149090" : [
>               {
>                   "Hotfix" : "Security Update",
>                   "InstalledOn" : ISODate("2018-02-24T00:00:00Z")
>               }
>           ]
>       }
>   }

Also, I couldn't figure out a way to build pipeline structure to get desired result.

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Comment: And what is your question? Is there anything wrong with the given output?

Comment: @NicoHaase Thanks for replying. The question I am asking is - I can't loop through all the KB Ids given in the document. Query I have used in Mongo Shell it's working for static 'key' which is KB2868626 in my case. 
I know it can be done through aggregate method. However, link I am following - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26465846/mongodb-aggregate-group-sum-query-translated-to-pymongo-query

doesn't provide much insights.